# Convert Android App to Blackberry using ADT Plugin Eclipse

Tags: android, blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have successfully converted an android app using ADT plugin in eclipse and have couple of confussed situations.

I went through this [Documentation](https://developer.blackberry.com/android/tools/) regarding the process but in this video still mention about the "Code signing keys" which is the Old process and now not valid any more... Instead we have to use Blackberry ID. This [Tutorial](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2013/08/code-signing-keys-be-gone-welcome-blackberry-id/) explains this in detail.

I my android application in the manifest file I have included followings.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

I followed the following steps in the process

1. Right click project -> Blackberry tools -> Add blackberry nature to project
2. Right click project -> Blackberry tools -> Veryfy APK
3. Right click project -> Blackberry tools -> Sign for blackberry world

When I perfrom the above step2 level I am getting the following warnings Problems section in eclipse

[image]

This [Tutorial](http://garthpoitras.com/blog/porting-android-apps-to-blackberry) explains that the the android application `targetSdkVersion` should be 10. But the problem is when I change the project build target to 10 as follows, I am getting lots of errors.

1. Right click project -> Properties -> Project Build target

**Questions**

1. How to successfully configure the Build target(Android app) to 10 in my application. Which is 17 at the moment?
2. The 3rd warning in the screen shot says to target to the latest which I can not do as it should be 10 according to our requirement to PORT android app to blackberry.
3. No Idea of the 1st warning message in the Screen shot.
4. Also before add it to Blackberry World do I have to change minimum OS version in the following place?
   (Right click project -> Properties -> Blackberry -> Minimum OS version)
5. Finally how can I have the exact version number I want in Blackberry Bar manifest file. It automatically adds that value taking Android Manifest file "versionCode" in to consideration, but it is confusing.

   For example when `android:versionCode="1"` Bar manifest creates `Package-Version: 1.0.1.0`

Comment: You get warnings, but does it sign it?

Comment: Ya it signs ok.... But I think if I proceed with the 2nd warning the App will run only in blackberry 10.2 OS version onwards and not in 10.0.... Also I can give up 1st and 2rd warning as they are lint warnings and will not effect that much. But pleasure if can avoid all warnings.... Also In my Questions set 4th and 5th are more confusing for the moment... Thanks........

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this the targetSdkVersion warning is related to project configuration, please do like below steps :

1) select the project by right-click.
2) choose "Properties" -> "BlackBerry" -> "APK Verification and Packaging"
3) for the item of "Minimum OS VERsion", select 10.2 instead of "default (2.0)"
4) re-run the verify command.

Good Luck.